# javascript: how to remove last entry?

Tags: javascript

Suppose i have the following JS code, i can only remove the whole characters whenever it receives non-acceptable character(s):

```
function checkInput() {
    document.getElementById("message").setAttribute('maxlength', (456));
    for (var i = 0; i < document.fr_upload.message.value.length; i++) {
        if (!checkLatin(document.fr_upload.message.value)) {
            alert("Your entry does not contain latin type.\n Please try again.")
            document.fr_upload.message.value = '';
            document.fr_upload.char_left.value = 0;
            return false;

        }
    }
}

function checkLatin(arg) {
    var latin = /^[\u0020-\u007E]*$/;
    if (arg.match(latin)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thus, how can i remove only non-acceptable character?

Comment: You should define what do you mean by "non-acceptable"

Comment: can you share `checkLatin`

Comment: @alfasin: i made a validation if(!checkLatin(document.fr_upload.message.value) so that any non-latin type will be stopped by message alert and so on ...

Comment: @ArunPJohny: function checkLatin(arg){
        var latin = /^[\u0020-\u007E]*$/;
        if(arg.match(latin)){
              return true;
        }
        else{
              return false;
        }
}

Comment: you want to remove non latin characters?

Comment: @ArunPJohny: So whenever user inputs non-latin characters, it will pop-up an alert and only remove non-latin char input. Currently, I will remove all entries whenever there's non-latin input.

Comment: did you try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function checkInput() {
    document.getElementById("message").setAttribute('maxlength', (456));

    var value = document.fr_upload.message.value;
    if (value && !/[^\u0020-\u007E]/.test(value)) {
        alert("Your entry contains non latin characters.\n Please try again.");
        document.fr_upload.message.value = value.replace(
                /[^\u0020-\u007E]/g, '');
        document.fr_upload.char_left.value = document.fr_upload.message.value.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the OP's code /[^\u0020-\u007E]/ matches latin characters, so you should invert the regex in the replace code to match the non-latin characters.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the non-latin characters you can use:

```
function removeNonLatin(arg) {
    var nonlatin = /!(^[\u0020-\u007E]*$)/g;
    arg = arg.replace(nonlatin , '');
    return arg;
}
```